# Hide navbar (bootstrap) on photoswipe image click

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, photoswipe

[image]

Like you can somehow see in the picture, my navbar is still visible when I'm inside the gallery view from PhotoSwipe. I really don't know how this happend.

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <!-- FOR MOBILE VIEW COLLAPSED BUTTON -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

      </div>

      <!-- Header Menu Bar
    ================================================== -->
      <div id="nav-main" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav main-nav">
          <li>
            <a class="activeNav" href="#home"> <span class="icon icon-home"></span> STARTSEITE</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#page-1"> <span class="icon icon-user"></span> ABOUT ME</a>
          </li>
          <!-- etc.. -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->
</header>
```

The Gallery/Photoswipe initialisation is 1:1 like the template inside the documentation. I remember it worked sometime while the navbar was buggy.

What is the easiest way to hide the navbar? Can't I somehow toggle the navbar on PhotoSwipe click and toggle it back on leave?

Answer (score 0):

this is usually caused by the z-index of class .navbar-fixed-top being a higher value than the photoswipe background class .pswp, best thing to do is inspect the photoswipe element in your browser and either increase the z-index for the photoswipe background or decrease the z-index of the bootstrap navbar-fixed-top.

```
.pswp {
    z-index: 2500;
}
```